# MouseLeftButtonDownEvent firing two times

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i  have a grid in xaml which contains an image/textblock/buttons in a row . In order to row respond to single click i added the following code in the cs file.

```
 this.radFilestoPrint.CellLoaded += new EventHandler<Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.CellEventArgs>(filesToPrintGrid_CellLoaded);

 void filesToPrintGrid_CellLoaded(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.CellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cell.Column != radFilestoPrint.Columns[4] && e.Cell.Column != radFilestoPrint.Columns[5])
            {
                e.Cell.AddHandler(GridViewCell.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(radFilestoPrint_MouseDoubleClick), true);
            }
        }
```

Now the problem is that the mousedownevent is firing two times. I checked the origin of the message as below and found that it is from the Image itself. I am setting the `e.Handled = true` after processing the message even though I noticed that i am recieving the `e.Handled`  as true from  the from the first time onwards.

```
  if (((FrameworkElement)e.Source).GetType() != typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Image))
  {
       return;    
  }
```

Why is the event firing two times? How should i prevent it?

Please advice.

Regards,

John.

Comment: Why is the event firing two times? How should i prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you handle your event in `worst place` and it handle for 2  time and with single Down event  it fire two event.

> foreach cell loaded not for your specified column
>   Try handle your **event in other place**

Comment: May be you handle your `cellloaded event` two time's

Comment: yes it will get handled since there are four columns.  i guess that just add the handler to cells. if there is an cell handler it will get replaced.

Comment: no it is not a solution and it is not the reason why the event is getting two times.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is a bug in WPF

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/29101/95353.aspx

Comment: Looks like the reference is about Silverlight Beta 2 to me